# A box has an unknown number of tickets serially numbered 1,2,...,N. Two tickets are drawn using simple random sampling without replacement

Tags: statistics, self-learning, estimation, sampling

A box has an unknown number of tickets serially numbered 1,2,...,N. Two tickets are drawn using simple random sampling without replacement (SRSWOR) from the box. If X and Y are the numbers on these two tickets and $Z = max(X,Y )$, show that

(a) Z is not unbiased for N

(b) $aX+bY +c$ is unbiased for N if and only if $ a+b = 2 \text{ and}\ c = −1.$

What is the the pmf of Z,  Any tips on how to proceed?

Comment: You do not need to know the exact distribution of $Z$ in order to answer (a). It is clear that $P(Z < N) > 0,$ and $P(Z > N) = 0$ so $E(Z) < N.$ // However, it is easy to get the distribution of $Z$ for special cases, such as $N = 2.$ (deterministic) and $N = 3.$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Comment (continued)** However, it should not be too hard for you
to find the distribution of $Z.$

Here is a simple simulation in R statistical software
for the case $N = 5.$ It seems that $Z$ takes values 2 through 5 with
respective probabilities $.1, .2, .3, .4,$ and that $E(Z) = 4.$ (Of course
simulation only provides a good approximation.)

```
n = 5;  box = 1:n
z = replicate(10^5, max(sample(box,2)))
hist(z, prob=T, br = (box)+.5, col="skyblue2")
mean(z)
## 4.00825  # Consistent with $E(Z) = 4.$
```

[image]

You can easily get the *exact* distribution of $Z$ by making a $5 \times 5$ square
array of points, representing possible values $X$ and $Y.$ What is the
probability of each point? What is the value of $Z$ for each point?
What is the exact distribution of $Z$? What is $E(Z)?$

Then maybe you can generalize the answers to larger values of $N$ without
making arrays of points.

For example, here is the histogram for $N = 10.$ It seems clear that $E(Z) < 10.$ (The red line shows the position of the mean.)

[image]

*Addendum:* In your last comments you turned to part (b). Consider
the special case in which $a = b = 1.$ Then let $W = X+Y-1.$ In case it helps, simulation
with $N = 10$ gives $E(W) \approx 10$ and the following histogram.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the help. I did follow the comment and used indicator variable for the proof , but i still need the distributions of x and y without which i cannot do the second part of the excercise.

Comment: if X has dicrete Uni[ 1, N ] , shouldnt y have  Uni[ 1, N-1], because of sampling without replacement?

Comment: Sorry, just coming back to edit my comment to mention sampling without replacement. But it's not necessarily ticket $N$ that's chosen on the first draw.

Comment: For X  : total no. of tickets present =N;   For Y: total no. of tickets present=N-1 [Since 1 ticket has already been choosen by X]. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: The dist'n fir the 2nd ball (given the first), is a discrete unif dist'n on the _remaining_ tickets. Maybe start by considering $a = b = 1.$ You can get the mean of a sum _without considering conditional info_ (but not the var of a sum). I need to abandon you now. Time for breakfast and errands here. Maybe back later. However, happy to give clues, but not to post complete solution.

Comment: What if $a = 2$ and $b = 0?$ Then $E(W) = 2E(X) +0 -1 = 2\frac{N+1}{2} -1 = N.$ // An important ingredient of estimation is missing from the parts of the problem you quote.:You not only want an estimator to be unbiased, but you also want it to have a small variance. // The continuous version of this problem is a standard exercise and perhaps easier to deal with: Take $n$ random obs $X_i$ from UNIF(0, $\theta$). Then $T = \frac{n+1}{n}\max(X_i) $ is unbiased  for $\theta$ and has the smallest variance among unbiased estimators.

Comment: The discrete problem, seeking the best estimator of $N,$ is known as the [German Tank Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/German_tank_problem). You may want to look at the Wikipedia article (perhaps ignoring the Bayesian parts for now). But this is _not_ related to your part (b).

Comment: Incorporate your comment into your answer.

Answer (score 1):

so i solved this question so you have to start in this way 
think what values Z can take? so z can 2,3,4,,,,N. Z can not  take the value 1 because if we take any two number them maximum value can not be one so what is the probability to take this no is given 
if z take 2 them its probability is 1/ (N c 2)     { there N c 2 is the N choose 2}
Z take   3 them its probability is  2/ (N c 2)

{ here numerate is 2 because there is two ways to take the value 3 is {(3,2) ,(3,1)} 
and so on if now if z take N so its probabilty is  (N-1)/(N c 2) 
so in this way you got the probabiltiy distribution .

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).